# File deletion fails silently

Tags: java, file, delete-file, bukkit

This is a question pertaining to Bukkit, although the problem lies in my actual Java code.

My problem is that I'm trying to delete the player data, however I'm unable to do so for unknown reasons. The Bukkit console shows no errors. I even used `File`'s `.getAbsolutePath()` to check if I was getting the right filepath, and I was. Displaying the result boolean also resulted in a `false`.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerLeave(PlayerQuitEvent event) {
    final File playerDat = new File("Hub/players/" + event.getPlayer().getName() + ".dat");
    this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            boolean playerDeleteSuccess = playerDat.delete();
            getLogger().info("Absolute path: " + playerDat.getAbsolutePath());
            getLogger().info("Success: " + playerDeleteSuccess);
        }
    }, 10L);
}
```

Comment: Do you have rights to delete the file ?

Comment: Why schedule it as a delayed task? It doesn't block.

Comment: @EJP I delayed it in case Bukkit is still writing to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ensured that you have closed any streams writing/reading to the file? As I understand it any open streams will block the file from being deleted.

Comment: I have, I set delay time to 2000 ticks (100 seconds) and no change was seen except a long delay.

Comment: But are there any streams left open? Are there any streams you have not called .close() on. If a file stream is not explicitly closed via .close() problems will occur.

Comment: Let me be clearer: whether or not bukkit is editing the file technically does not matter. Whether or not there are open I/O streams reading/writing to/from the file does matter. Your delay shouldn't make a difference - make sure the connected iostreams are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your file:

```
final File configFile = new File(this.getDataFolder(), event.getPlayer().getName() + ".dat");
configFile.delete();
```

Instead of getting a path, you're just getting the default path with this code, and deleting the config using that information.

I think that your problem is that you're not telling bukkit what folder to look in, you're only telling it the path of the file, but it doesn't know where to start from.

To create a config file within a folder that is inside your plugin's data folder, you could do this:

```
final File configFile = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "/Hub/players/" + event.getPlayer().getName() + ".dat");
configFile.delete();
```

Before you can get a config file, you need to check the default data folder. The default data folder is a folder named whatever your plugin is named.

Also, you may want to try putting this in your onDisable() method, and see if it works there, just as a test, though.